# Stop video html5 on close modal Materialize, using jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, html5-video, materialize

I am using Materialize in app ruby on rails and want video stop closing modal Materialize.
Help me please.

```
<% @chapter.episode.each do |episode| %>
    <a class="btn modal-trigger" href="#<%= episode.name %>"><%= episode.name %></a>
  <div id="<%= episode.name %>" class="modal">
    <i id="close" title="Cerrar" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-green right material-icons">close</i>
    <div class="modal-content">
        <video id="<%= episode.name %>"  width="320" height="240" controls>
        <source id="<%= episode.name %>" src="<%= episode.url %>" type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2'">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are setting the same `id` for multiple tags (`div`, `video`, `source`). ID must be unique in entire document.
Considering that you want to stop video when modal close, you can use the callback for complete event (modal close), in your Javascript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var videos = $("video");

    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
        complete: function() {
            videos.each(function(){
                this.pause();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This will pause all videos when modal close.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but it came up for me in search. I solved it by adding video into modal when it opens, then removing it when it closes.  Here's my work.

```
$(document).on('click','.video-butt',function(){
    $('#video-modal .video-container').html('<iframe id="myIframe" width="300" height="200" src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '?rel=0" allowfullscreen="true" ></iframe>'); // embed video
    $('#video-modal').modal('open');
    return false;
})
function videoTrash(){ //remove video embed on close
    $('#video-modal .video-container').empty();
}
$('#video-modal').modal({onCloseEnd:videoTrash}); // initialize materialize modal
```

html

```
<div id="video-modal" class="modal black">
    <div class="modal-content white-text">
        <div class="video-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the trigger link

```
<a class="btn btn-flat video-butt" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hO4tW8Py2xc">watch the video</a>
```